# List and sort keywords by value alphabetically php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

As the title suggests i want to list (mix all the values) and sort keywords of all rows by value alphabetically in php and mysql.

I have multiple rows with the column's name "keywords", separated with commas :

- voiture électrique, recyclage des batteries
- Télétravail, travail à domicile, bureau
- réchauffement climatique, effet de serre
- coworking, travail

Here is my code :

```
<?php

include_once ("config.php");
$query_top = "SELECT keywords FROM market WHERE keywords != ''"; 

if ($stmt_top = $bdd->prepare($query_top)) {

$stmt_top->execute();

$result_top = $stmt_top->get_result();

$num_of_rows_top = $result_top->num_rows;

$stmt_top->close();
}

while ($row_kw = $result_top->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$keywords = $row_kw['keywords'];

$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $keywords)));
sort($array);
$array = implode('<br>', $array);
echo $array . '<br/>';

}

?>
```

My result need to be sort by value alphabetically like :

- Awesome
- Beauty
- Coworking

Any ideas?

**EDIT** FINAL WORKING CODE IS :

```
$array = [];

while ($row_kw = $result_top->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$array = array_merge($array, explode(',', $row_kw['keywords']));
}

$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
sort($array);

// FR language
$collator = new Collator('fr_FR');

$collator->asort( $array );


$array = implode('<br>', $array);
echo $array . '<br/>';
```

Thanx a lot to @Kinglish for the help.

Comment: Storing data in comma separated format is a fundamental design mistake which leads to this kind of problem

Comment: Exact @ADyson, like inserting from a textarea to multiple rows: `include_once ("config.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{ 
$text = trim($_POST['keywords']);
$textAr = explode(",", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r chars

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    mysqli_query($bdd, "INSERT INTO keywords VALUES(NULL,'1','".$line."','4512452455','2021-07-12 17:30:23')") or die (mysqli_error($bdd));
} 
}`

Comment: Ok, so are you going to fix this mistake and have a secondary table with a foreign key to store the keywords?

Comment: Exactly, but i'll try to find the solution first. ;)

Comment: The solution to your question will be a lot easier if you fix the data structure first...that was my point.

Comment: You are true, but its ok now, i just updated the final code. Thanx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your array outside the loop that is building it

```
$array=[];
while ($row_kw = $result_top->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_merge($array, explode(',', $row_kw['keywords']);
}
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
sort($array);
$array = implode('<br>', $array);
echo $array . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Thanx for your help. I just fixed your code : `$array = [];
while ($row_kw = $result_top->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_merge($array, explode(',', $row_kw['keywords']));
}
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
sort($array);
$array = implode('<br>', $array);
echo $array . '<br/>';` but it show a blank page.

Comment: and here I was thinking i fixed your code :)

Comment: Yes :-D i saw you put two `sort($array);` in the code, why ?

Comment: 0oops, a typo. it's removed, thanks!. Still, did this help solve your issue?

Comment: No problem ;) Nope i got a blank page, im trying to find where is the problem.

Comment: Fixed (post updated) ! ;-) Thanx a lot for your help.